# getting error of import in airflow DAG in google cloud composer

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a DAG in google composer (airflow) that imports:

from airflow.contrib.sensors.gcs_sensor import GoogleCloudStorageObjectSensor

when I run the DAG I got this error:

"ImportError: No module named sensors.base_sensor_operator"

Basically I want to check if a file exists in a bucket before doing something else.

Here is the complete python code:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.subdag_operator import SubDagOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_bq import 
GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator
from airflow.contrib.sensors.gcs_sensor import 
GoogleCloudStorageObjectSensor


CONNECTION_ID = 'something'

default_args = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2018, 8, 21, 0, 0),
}

def print_hello():
return 'youtube folder exists!!'

with DAG('DATA_TRANSFER_GCP_BUCKET_TO_BQ2', 
schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1), 
 default_args=default_args ) as dag: 

 gcp_sensorBucket=GoogleCloudStorageObjectSensor(
 task_id='gcp_sensorbucket',
 bucket='/aa_youtube_new/2018/06/04/', 
 #bucket='{{var.value.gcp_youtube_video_bucket}}/2018/06/04/',
 object='*.csv', 
 google_cloud_conn_id=CONNECTION_ID

)
hello_operator = PythonOperator(task_id='hello_task', 
python_callable=print_hello)
hello_operator.set_upstream(gcp_sensorBucket)
```

Comment: I am having the same problem with these commands: from airflow.contrib.operators.gcs_to_s3 import GoogleCloudStorageToS3Operator from airflow.contrib.operators.s3_to_gcs_operator import S3ToGoogleCloudStorageOperator. Are the contrib operators installed by default? I am using composer 1.2 and airflow 1.9

Comment: Picarus: Your case also requires to use Airflow 1.10, since the gcs_to_s3 and s3_to_gcs_operator didn't exist prior to this version. Since October 26th, [Airflow 1.10 is available for Composer 1.3](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions).

Answer (score 1):

I see that the import from base_sensor_operator was added in the [version 1.10 of Airflow](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/contrib/sensors/gcs_sensor.py). This was not present in versions [1.8](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-8-stable/airflow/contrib/sensors/gcs_sensor.py) and [1.9](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-9-stable/airflow/contrib/sensors/gcs_sensor.py). Instead, the import was done as follows:

```
from airflow.operators.sensors import BaseSensorOperator
```

So, checking the sensors, the related [sensor for Airflow 1.10](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/master/airflow/sensors) is under sensors but for Airflow 1.9 and 1.8, the sensor is under [operators](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-9-stable/airflow/operators/sensors.py).

So, this issue seems to be related to the versioning of Composer and Airflow, but Airflow 1.10 wasn't available for Composer on August. In fact, this issue was reported  on [Google's Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/118713709) and the response is to solve this by using Apache Airflow version 1.10, which can be included on the [version 1.3 of Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions).

Answer (score 0):

Which Composer version are you using? I copy and paste your DAG code into a newly created Composer environment [composer-1.1.0-airflow-1.9.0](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/release-notes#august_17_2018_composer-110-airflow-190), it works out of the box for me.

Here's the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I have the same problem that OP with 1.2 composer and 1.9 airflow.